Linker error using xCode/JUCE to compile VST3
I am getting this error when trying to compile a VST3 plugin in Xcode. Any pointers to how to solve  this woud be very helpful:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"VST3::StringConvert::convert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, char16_t*)", referenced from:
Steinberg::Vst::HostApplication::getName(char16_t*) in include_juce_audio_plugin_client_VST3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
This is the first time compiling a plugin for Mac so I am not familiar with any of the info in the error message.

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

The code referred to in the error message is not by me but from the code used by JUCE and opened in Xcode. If anyone has experience of this that would be helpful.

Just to let you know. The error went away when I replaced JUCE 5.4.5 with a later version. For some reason it didn't work with Xcode 11.3.1
